# Accessing object by enum returns any instead of undefined

Tags: typescript, enums

Having a structure like this:

```js
enum Company {
  Google,
  Facebook
}

function getRating(company: Company) {
  const ratingMap = {
    [Company.Google]: 1000,
    [Company.Facebook]: 2000
  }

  const result = ratingMap[company]

  return result
}
```

TypeScript understands that `result` is a `number`. But if I list **not all** the `Company` values in the `ratingMap`, then the `result` has type `any`. I want ts to resolve this expression into `number | undefined` rather than `any`.

```js
function getRating(company: Company) {
  const ratingMap = {
    [Company.Google]: 1000,
    // [Company.Facebook]: 2000
  }

  const result = ratingMap[company] // Element implicitly has an 'any'

  return result
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9hADgQxATygbwFBSgcTjgHMAbYAGlygDFkBjYAIyIGtsBfbbAMzBHoAXAJZwQUYsEEAlZCJDEAFPQQp0ALlirUaAJRZqKkAGdBUAE5zhCgLLJEUALwG8eANrwkOgHSES5AF1NAEYABnCqVygAemioD210bzpGFjhWIKgAJnDQ6i5DMVMLYGMwUjNnS3liO0Q3FS90AO48cykwc3F2sorOIA)

I know I can set a type for `ratingMap` like this:

```js
const ratingMap: Partial<Record<Company, number>>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9hADgQxATygbwFBSgcTjgHMAbYAGlygDFkBjYAIyIGtsBfbbAMzBHoAXAJZwQUYsEEAlZCJDEAFPQQp0ALlirUaAJRZqKkAGdBUAE5zhCgLLJEmgArJzI5KQA804CvMATD3gkHQoocAgmYHMAPmioAF4DPDwAbSC1NAA6QhJyAF1NAEYABlKqZKgAekqoNO10TLpGFjhWAqgAJlLi6i5DMVMLYGMwUjNEy3liO0QUlWD0PO48cykwc3FVkbHOIA)

and it would give me expected `number | undefined`. But I think there should be a simpler elegant solution. Maybe a specific tsconfig property.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
function getRating(company: Company): number | undefined {
  const ratingMap = {
    [Company.Google]: 1000,
    [Company.Facebook]: 2000
  }

  const result = ratingMap[company]

  return result
}
```

This should do exectly what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work if you [comment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9hADgQxATygbwLACgpQDiccA5gDbAA0eBAYsgMbABGJA1ngL554BmYEIwAuASzggopYMIBKyMSFIAKRghToAXLHWo0ASm3gILYACcoAHyiCAJsD6iQwW1lpQ1IAM7CoZhU6kALLIiFAAvG74BFAA2vBIegB0xGSUALraAIwADHk00QQA9EVxCRpoSQzMbHDsmVAATHk57jy47p4+fsBeYOS+kf6KwaGxaono6bzRZjJgZpJzfQPcQA) one line in the map.

Comment: Okey I see but it would work if you ignore the typescript error, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use the es6 map. Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9hADgQxATygbwLACgpQDiccA5gDbAA0eBAYsgMbABGJA1ngL554BmYEIwAuASzggopYMIBKyMSFIAKRghToAXLHWo0ASiy98UNSADOwqACcFopQFlkiKAF4oIYAHcoTxAB5wCBZgayoPSBDrAD5lAG1aKDj4JD0AOmIySnCARgAGAoBdGhNk3XQ0hmY2OHZwgCYCvMKCRML9AG5jAjNLG2BzMHIrd1tFUj806WFVcoMuk2sZMGtJJcHh7mNKKzH7UgA1ZHIwYChtIKioAB8oQQATYD57YHu3KRl5ceUUjTQMkgUYCdYzHUIzPZKI4nYEdIA).

```
enum Company {
  Google,
  Facebook
}

function getRating(company: Company) {

  const ratingMap = new Map<number, number>([
  [Company.Google, 1000],
  [Company.Facebook, 2000]  
  ]);

  const result = ratingMap.get(company);
  return result
}

let ratingValue : number | undefined = getRating(Company.Google);    
alert(ratingValue);
```

Comment: Yes, `Map` solves. But I'm trying to find a way using just an object)

Answer (score 0):

The type of the `result` is not `any`, it is just inferred as `any` due to the error. Specifically, the error is that you *index* a type that lacks an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) with a numeric union of `0 | 1` (values of `Company.Google` and `Company.Facebook` respectively) while deferring inference of what type `ratingMap` is to the compiler. Unsurprisingly, the type is inferred as:

```js
const ratingMap: {
    0: number;
}
```

If you enable the [`suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors) backwards compatibility compiler flag, you will notice that the error disappears when indexing the `ratingMap` with `Company` (although the `result` will still be inferred as `any` because the flag simply *suppresses* the error).

---

You need to explicitly tell the compiler what `ratingMap` is: a partial record with keys of type `Company` and values of type `number`, which is trivially expressed as `Partial<Record<Company, number>>`. The `result` type will correctly be inferred as `number | undefind` then:

```js
enum Company {
  Google,
  Facebook
}

function getRating(company: Company) {
  const ratingMap: Partial<Record<Company, number>> = {
    [Company.Google]: 1000
  };

  const result = ratingMap[company]; // number | undefined

  return result;
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mp9zMW)

---

An alternative solution is to ensure the compiler that `company` is definitely a key on the `ratingMap` with a user-defined type guard. This is probably the most type-safe way:

```js
enum Company {
  Google,
  Facebook
}

const isKeyof = <T>(obj:T, key: string | number | symbol): key is keyof T => key in obj;

function getRating(company: Company) {
  const ratingMap = {
    [Company.Google]: 1000
  };

  const result = isKeyof(ratingMap, company) ?  ratingMap[company] : void 0; // number | undefined

  return result;
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3yKLw)

Comment: Well, this is the only way I have found. I just thought TS could understand that if the object contains not all the values from enum, it'd understand that in some cases indexing give us undefined.

Comment: @tolec well, you can also define a type guard for ensuring the compiler that `company` is a key that exists on the object literal. I added the explanation and example to the answer. This is probably the safest way to go about it as it gives both compile and run-time assurance.

Comment: Thank, but still overhead :) It's interesting why TS doesn't show his best in this case. It's clear that indexing the object by unknown key give us undefined. So why not to mark a result as `number | undefined`. It's especially useful when we're indexing an object [on the fly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9hADgQxATygbwFBSgcTjgHMAbYKAXigHJCTyaAaXKAMWQGNgAjIgayq0O3PnH41sAX2zZOcEAGcALlHlJUGavA3oAdCN4DZAMzAhOygJYKoxYMoBKyayGIAKdSnQAuWAm80AEosVgAnBzAwkFC8PABtHUC9ejJgAF0-AEYABjyWOKgAeiKoRIDNAy4jcUyoACY8nNYpeK9NdOkgA)

Comment: @tolec well... it's the best you can do :) There is simply no other way, I am afraid. It is true that it we do that in JS all the time, however, the team behind TS prefers to err on the side of soundness in such matters (meaning you have to be explicit about allowing this, or the compiler defaults to treating this as a potential error). IRRC, the indexing checking on object literals was tightened at some point.